# will Virtual Box NAT Supports "Bandwidth" Command?

Tags: virtualbox, nat

I am using VirtualBox in windows 8 for launching guest OS and NAT as a virtual network adapter.
i want to know whether the guest OS supports network bandwidth control(I should get a notification when data usage crosses a particular limit) or not ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:
Nope. VMWare on the other hand got bandwidth limiting capabilities (like throttling and introducing lag/jitter/loss.)

But bandwidth meter? No.
Use a software for that. It's called "Bandwidth meter". (It's not free, but that's the one I used and the one worked perfectly.)

And with this I totally go into SU scope: Try updating your modem software. Most new software contains a bandwidth meter feature. (In case that's why you are looking for such feature in VBox.)